# Why does my RegExp in JavaScript give this result?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a question about '(x)' RegExp pattern. Here is my code.

```
// normal code:
console.log('bar foo'.replace( /(...) (...)/, '$1 $2' )) //foo bar
```

It matches 3 length str and make each become group, and changes their position it`s my understanding.

```
  console.log('bar foo'.replace( /(...) (..)/, '$1' )) //baro
```

Why does this RegExp match 'bar' and 'o'? How can it bring 'o' to the result?

I think result should be only 'bar', because of `$1`, only can match one pattern.

Comment: you haven't anchored the regex to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/(...) (..)/` matches the following characters:

```
bar foo
^^^^^^
```

It matches three characters, followed by a space, followed by two characters. These characters get replaced with `bar`:

```
bar fo => bar
```

Now we apply this substitution to the whole string:

```
bar foo => baro
      ^       ^
```

`.replace` only replaces the characters that match the expression. All other characters are left in place. The `o` you see in the output is the last `o` in `foo`, which wasn't touched by the regular expression. It is not captured by the capture if that's what you think.

```js
console.log('fast food'.replace(/foo/, 'bar'));
```

And we can easily proof this by adding another character after `$1`:

```js
console.log('bar foo'.replace( /(...) (..)/, '$1-' )) // bar-o
```

Comment: thanx u ,bro your answer is helpful to me.I don`t understand 'replace'`s rule,so I think it only replace the whole str, your anwser help me know it only replace it`s pattern. u r so nice